# Uneven font xheight - win webkit fix

Tags: css, windows, fonts, webkit

Was having an unusual css font xheight issue in Windows Webkit. Wanted to post the fix for it as it took me a couple of hours to figure out what was causing it.

### The problem:

[image: uneven xheight on the h1 strapline]

The uneven xheight on the h1 strapline - caused by a positioning margin and the relationship between line-height and font-size messing with the xheight (which can be seen in the inspector (margin: 30px 0)).

Comment: There is no real problem statement and no code in the question. The reference to “xheight” probably means the variation in glyph sizes (the x-height property of a font is something different) – for some unspecified font under some unspecified circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

### The fix

Was simply removing the margin in the CSS and positioning using line-height with a corresponding font-size instead. Simple!

**Code updated to:**

```
font-weight: 600;
font-family: 'proxima-nova-alt-condensed', "Arial Narrow", Arial, sans-serif; 
font-size: 28px;
color: #FFFFFF;
line-height: 45px;
```